# Watch: Only print to screen if output has changed since last output

Tags: output, watch

I'm running a process and I'm counting the number of threads with

`ps huH p <PID_OF_U_PROCESS> | wc -l`

I can run this thread with `watch` like this;

`watch -n 1 ps huH p <PID_OF_U_PROCESS> | wc -l`

This will output the number of threads the process is running, but usually that number doesn't change.

How can I only print the new number to screen if it changed from the last time the command was run?

For example:

`64
65
64`
(a few minutes go by)
`65`

Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pipe to `uniq`:

```
while ps -o nlwp= -p "$pid"; do sleep 1; done | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

`watch` is not capable of doing this directly. Although you can highlight differences in the command output (via option `-d`) or exit when the output changes (via option `-g`) it is not possible to display the output of more than one run. But you can achieve this via other common tools.

One of many possible solutions:

`last=""; while true; do cur="$(ps h -o nlwp -p <PID>)"; if ! [ "$cur" = "$last" ]; then last="$cur"; echo "$(date) $cur"; fi; sleep 1; done`

Or more readable:

```
last=""
while true
do
    cur="$(ps h -o nlwp -p <PID>)"
    if ! [ "$cur" = "$last" ]
    then
        last="$cur"
        echo "$(date) $cur"
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Explanation: The `ps` option `-o nlwp` directly prints the number of threads, so you don't have to call `wc -l`. You can also use `$(pidof programname)` instead of `<PID>` in order to determine the process ID automatically. I also added the current date via `$(date)` which seems useful to me. If you don't like it then just remove it.

Comment: If you want it to clear the screen like `watch`, add a `clear` statement on a line before the `echo`.

Comment: But then you won't see the previous thread count, defeating the whole purpose of not using `watch` directly.